# Is the sum of two white random process a white process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random

Given a real-valued white random process $X[k]$ with zero mean, we define:

$Y[k]=X[k]+X[k-1]$

Is $Y[k]$ also a white process? What if $X[k]$ is strictly white?

Comment: Hint: What is $\mathrm{Cov}(Y[k]Y[k+1])$?

Comment: I'm gussing $R_xx[1]$ ?